# Meaning of SocialEvents in Asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to generate a calender to show monthly reports using asp.net...However, whatever examples I found online has the following the line of code which I cannot understand.

```
System.Data.DataView view = socialEvents.DefaultView;
```

What is SocialEvents and how do I declare it...Please explain.

Cheers
Shivangi

Comment: [System.Data.DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a property [DefaultView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that returns [System.Data.DataView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - so I suspect that is what it is. As to how you declare it it would be `var socialEvents = new System.Data.DataTable();` - However, you probably need to find a basic tutorial as this doesn't help you fill your table.

Comment: Yes I got it thanks, it was a simple datatable and the rest of the properties are that of a data table. Thanks!